# Is there an algorithm for placing 2-dimensional embeddings into a grid so they can be displayed?

Tags: pca, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, embeddings

I’m using PCA to reduce images down to 2d embeddings and I’d like to display the images in a grid.

[The Pudding did something like this with book covers](https://pudding.cool/2019/07/book-covers/), using tsne and a library called [RasterFairy, by Quasimondo](https://github.com/Quasimondo/RasterFairy), but I was hoping to find an algorithm, rather than just relying on a black-box library.

Here's an example how this might work:

- I have `1,000` images with the dimensions `224 x 224 x 3`
- I then flatten those images so my dataset is `1,000 x 150,528`
- then I use PCA to reduce each image's dimensions from `150,528` to `2`
- then I'd use this algorithm to sort these `1,000` data points into a `100 x 100` grid.

Here's a gif from RasterFairy's github repo that will hopefully help demonstrate what I mean:

[image: raster fairy example gif]

Comment: Clear question. Could you add a drawing which illustrates the technicalities of your approach to 'embeddings' ? That would make your question clearer. Thx.

Comment: the linked githubs sketch out this approach: define the cost of each point to be the distance between its 2d embedding, and the position its assigned on the grid. then we simply want to select the assignments the minimize the sum of these costs. there's efficient solvers for this matching problem

Comment: @match-maker-ee Thanks -- I added an example of how it might work and a gif to help demonstrate visually